# IO::Select and adding a tag to the handle

Tags: perl, select, filehandle

I'm wondering what's the best way to add additional data to a handle when I'm using `IO::Select`?

Basically I'd like to add a handle to `IO::Select` but also have additional info attached to that handle that I could retrieve later.

Note: I know I could keep a separate data structure which holds a handle and additional data but that would require coordinating two data structures and that's probably going to cause more problems than its worth.

Comment: One approach is to save the [file number](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html) of the handle in a hash map with the additional information, see also [Comparing filehandle with glob returned by IO::Select::can_read()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3868068/2173773)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A direct way follows from [IO::Select](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Select.html) docs for `add` method

> Each handle can be an IO::Handle object, an integer or an array reference where the first element is an IO::Handle or an integer.

So there, there's "an array reference" that one may use.

An example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
use POSIX qw(:sys_wait);
use IO::Select;

my $sel = IO::Select->new;

my @procs;
for my $job (1..3) {
    pipe my ($reader, $writer);
    $sel->add( [$reader, "job-$job"] );  # add a tag to the handle

    my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";

    if ($pid == 0) {
        close $reader;
        sleep rand 4;
        say $writer "\tkid $$ (job $job)";
        close $writer;
        exit; 
    }   
    close $writer;
    push @procs, $pid;
}       
say "Started processes @procs\n";

# Read from pipes when ready, print piped messages
while ( my @ready = $sel->can_read ) {
    foreach my $p (@ready) {
        my ($handle, $tag) = @$p;
        say "Reading from fileno ", $handle->fileno, ", tag: ", $tag;
        print while <$handle>;
        $sel->remove($p);      # *this* order: remove then close
        close $handle;
    }   
}   

# Reap
my $msg = "\nExited (with status): ";
my $kid = 0; # poll to reap
while (($kid = waitpid -1, WNOHANG) > -1) {
    $msg .= "$kid ($?) " if $kid > 0; 
    sleep 0.1;
}   
say $msg;
```

Prints

```
Started processes 15679 15680 15681

Reading from fileno 5, tag: job-2
        kid 15680 (job 2)
Reading from fileno 4, tag: job-1
        kid 15679 (job 1)
Reading from fileno 6, tag: job-3
        kid 15681 (job 3)

Exited (with status): 15680 (0) 15679 (0) 15681 (0)
```

Comment: I didn't know that! In the past, I used the file handle as a key to a hash that contained the remaining info. But I can't think of a situation where that would be better than using your approach

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, this is really handy, a great feature -- i just found out, by following up on the question.  (It got me curious so I started reading docs closely ... I was really hoping for something in `IO::Handle` but never got that far. :).  I've always had additional data structures as well.